# How to use windows azure table as your identity provider for Windows Store App?

Tags: azure, windows-store-apps, azure-table-storage

I'm building a windows store app and I want to use Windows Azure Table as my identity provider. I tried using Azure AD it works for a month but since it is still on preview mode on mobile services it keeps on changing a lot of method.
Is there a way to store my user credentials to azure table and use it to authorized a windows store app?

Comment: Do you intend to store user's AD credentials in Azure Table or do you want your users to create a username/password that you will store in Azure Table?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, Yes I dont want to use AD anymore. And you are correct I want users to create their username and password that will be stored in azure table then use that credentials to login to the windows store app. New user will also use the same windows store app to create new registration. The 1st view will have login and register button.

Comment: Personally I would not recommend rolling out your own username/password system because of the complexities involved in managing them (and it gets somewhat compounded if you use Table Storage to store this information). If Azure AD is not working out for you, may be take a look at other identity providers like Microsoft Account, Facebook Google etc.

Comment: Our target market dont use facebook or google, they dont even have email. I was thinking of similar to this https://identityazuretable.codeplex.com/

Comment: Aah ... I see. Makes complete sense now. I haven't tried the project you referred but see how that works. Basically you would want to expose this functionality through an API running as a separate website which handles the authentication. So I guess, you could use this code as is in your API. Your users would put in their credentials in their phones and your app would call this API for authentication. API would in turn call table service to validate the credentials. Not sure if this helps but do give it a try.

Comment: Hi gaurav, thank for the reply. is it ok to send it to your blog the full details? How I was thinking similar to this implementation http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2015/05/06/sign-in-to-mobile-services-using-custom-authentication-from-a-windows-client.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this should be the answer: I haven't tried the project you referred but see how that works. Basically you would want to expose this functionality through an API running as a separate website which handles the authentication. So I guess, you could use this code as is in your API. Your users would put in their credentials in their phones and your app would call this API for authentication. API would in turn call table service to validate the credentials. Not sure if this helps but do give it a try. - Gaurav Mantri